# ggplot2 y value as "number of rows"?

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph

I want to make a grouped bar graph whereby x = Quarter_Year and y is the number of apartments, grouped by size of house.

The size of house is grouped like so:

```
data$size <- cut(data$Area..Sqft., breaks=c(0,500,1000,1500,2000,2500,3000,Inf),labels = c("0-500", "500-1000", "1000-1500", "1500-2000", "2000-2500","2500-3000", ">3000"))
```

I then tried to use count(data) as well as n(rows) data but, of course in both cases, the resulting graph would only return '77957' which is the total number of rows in my dataframe.

This is what I have tried:

```
rows<- count(data)
rows

z<-ggplot(data=data,aes(x=Quarter_Year, y=rows,fill=size))+
  geom_bar(stat='identity',position='dodge')+
  ggtitle("number of units")
```

I'm not too sure how it works so I have also tried `aes(x=Quarter_Year, y=size,fill=rows)` which doesn't work either. It will always return an error: "Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type data.frame. Defaulting to continuous."

I know my code is definitely wrong but I don't know where or how to make it such that the graph would reflect the what I want to see. Hope that this question is phrased clearly and thank you for your help.

Comment: as the error says - . `dplyr::count` (which I strongly assume you are using to create `rows`, returns a data frame (or tibble), thus you are passing a data frame to your y

Comment: for us to help better, we'd need a tiny bit more help from you, to create a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: try "rows <- as.numeric(count(data))", does that work? I'm having some difficulty following it though. You could try nrow(data) rather than count()?